# Hiding empty rows from Crosstab in BIRT

Tags: birt, crosstab

my problem is maybe simple but i don't get it.
i have this Crosstab :

[image: Crosstab]

So my idea is to hide all rows where ALL data fields ("Wert_Bezeichnung") are empty. But this is not possible easy if i get it right, because the birt renderer thinks the rows are never be empty because the left two columns ("Position" and "Bezeichnung") are never be empty. that are the row names.

Is it possible to hide the rows without touching the java code behind?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you describe the issue, it seems these empty rows are generated by the dataset itself. Double-check if property "Show empty rows" of this crosstab is unchecked.

Anyway, you should just have to add a dataset filter with an expression excluding empty rows.

- Edit the main dataset of your datacube
- In "Filters" tab, add a new condition
- select field "Wert_Bezeichnung" and operator "Is not null"

If it doesn't work, it means these rows are loaded with something different than a null value, for example an empty string. You need to adjust the dataset filter accordingly.

Comment: great thats it, it didn't know the filters option and didn't know how powerful they are . thanks !!